# How to estimate mle in functional response

Tags: r, mle

So I have been trying to understand on how do you estimate Maximum likelihood estimates in R, here in the Gammarus dataset of package frair, what is by=0.1, a=1.2, h=0.08 and T=40/24, how do you get these values. Can someone please explain it to me ?

```
with(gammarus, plot(density, eaten, 
     xlab = "Prey Density", ylab = "No. Prey Eaten"))
x <- with(gammarus, seq(from = min(density), to = max(density), 
       by = 0.1))
lines(x, rogersII(X = x, a = 1.2, h = 0.08, T = 40/24), col='grey50', lty=2)
lines(x, rogersII(X = x, a = 0.6, h = 0.16, T = 40/24), col='grey50', lty=2)
```

I am expecting to know about functional response analysis and maximum likelihood estimation in detail.

Comment: Are you just generally asking how to perform MLE in R? I would start with the package `fitdistrplus`. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/index.html. This might also be a relevant post from Stats Exchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best

Comment: Have you tried the help file for this `rogersII()` function? That should tell you what those arguments are

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can expect Stack Overflow to teach you "about functional response analysis and maximum likelihood estimation in detail" - that's too broad a topic for a SO question, which is intended to solve a **particular** programming problem.

```r
library(frair)
data(gammarus)
## adding a bit of noise makes it easier to identify overlapping/repeated points
plot(jitter(eaten) ~ jitter(density), gammarus)
lines(x, rogersII(X = x, a = 1.2, h = 0.08, T = 40/24), col='grey50', lty=2)
lines(x, rogersII(X = x, a = 0.6, h = 0.16, T = 40/24), col='grey50', lty=2)
```

The parameters used here are **examples** only, probably derived by visually examining the data (and knowing that the attack rate `a` corresponds to the initial slope of the functional response curve and `1/h` corresponds to the asymptote at high densities: `T` is used for the exposure time of the experiment).

From `?frair::gammarus`:

> Total experimental time was 40 hours.

Whoever wrote the example wanted the time units to be in days rather than hours (`a` has units of 1/time and `h` has units of time), so they used `T = 40/24` as the duration of the experiment (the experimental duration `T` must be specified for Rogers-type functional responses that allow for depletion, but not for simple Holling-type responses).

To estimate the parameters, you need to use `frair_fit`; you **must provide reasonable starting values**, which is one reason for doing the preliminary graph.

```r
ff <- frair_fit(eaten ~ density, gammarus, response = 'rogersII',
    start=list(a = 1.2, h = 0.08), fixed=list(T=40/24))
## add line to existing plot
lines(ff, col = 2)
```

One place you could look for more information on functional responses and MLEs (besides in the published literature) would be [here](https://math.mcmaster.ca/%7Ebolker/emdbook/index.html), e.g. chap 3/p. 12, all of chaps 6/7 ...

[image]

Comment: so the author has used this  function frair_fit, to estimate the values of  a and h, but after running the code the a and h  are completely different
##
## Response: rogersII
## Description: Roger's type II decreasing prey function
## Optimised variables: a, h
## Fixed va riables: T
##
## Coefficients:
##a         h         T
##1.423 0.180 1.667

Comment: is there a specific way of estimating these a and h values as well or the frair_fit function will do the job,, and also what is the way of providing reasonable values is it a random values or a calculated one as well

Comment: so i tried the hollings equation  the values here a and h are very similar to that of taken in the example, However iam unable to figure out why T=40/24                                                                                       formula: eaten ~ density * a/(1 + a * Th * density)

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a  1.170713   0.170545   6.865 6.59e-11 ***
Th 0.092173   0.009096  10.133  < 2e-16 ***

Comment: is this what you meant by preliminary graph to estimate attack rate and handling time.     data=Gammarus
plot(density, eaten, xlim = c(0, 30), ylab = "Number eaten",xlab = "Initial density")
lines(lowess(density, eaten))
meanvals = tapply(eaten, density, mean)
densvals = unique(density) 
lines(densvals, meanvals, lty = 5, col="blue")
lms = smooth. Spline(density, eaten, df=5)
ps = predict(lms, x = 0:30)
lines(ps, lty = 2,col="red")
how do you interpret it?